# Understanding machine precision based on bit representation

Tags: math, floating-point, decimal, precision, bit

I am trying to understand how this is calculated:

A computer program that represents numbers as follows: 1 bit for the overall
sign, 5 bits for the exponent, and 20 bits for the mantissa. Obviously we need to use a bias to represent the positive and negative numbers. Based on this, how would i calculate the machine precision and the largest possible number?

Comment: What is the floating point base? Are numbers normalized? If both binary and normalized, then does the representation use a non-stored leading one bit? What are the largest and smallest exponents? Knowing 5 bit storage is not sufficient. It might be any of [-15,16], [-16,15], and [-15, 15] with a value reserved for infinities and NaNs.

Comment: Also, are the 20 bits for the full significand (with the leading bit) or the reduced significand (without the leading bit)?

Answer (score 0):

One way to get an idea is to test when the program rounds of to zero. You can you this code in python.

```
N = 52
a = 1.0-2**(-N); 
print "%1.25f" % a
```

Try for different values of N. When the print out gives zero for the lowest N, it will give you an indication on how many bits are used for the significant. The print statement is to ensure that the program really sees the number as zero and not only displays zero.

Comment: Did you mean to print `a-1` after setting `a` to `a = 1.0-2**(-N)`? In any case, this is not helpful. The OP is asking about a hypothetical situation in which a non-standard floating-point format is used, and the number of bits in the significand of the hypothetical format is known.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the IEEE standard, the formula for the representation of numbers is:

```
number = sign*(1+2^(-m)*significand)*2^(exponent-bias)
```

where `m` is the number of bits used to store the (integer) significand (or mantissa), and `bias` is equal to `2^(e-1) - 1` where `e` is the number of bits used to store the exponent.

Let's see what we can derive from that. Note that

- The value of `significand` ranges between `0` and `2^m - 1` (in your case: between 0 and 1048575).
- The value of `exponent` ranges between `0` and `2^e - 1`. However, both extremal values are reserved for exceptions (subnormal numbers, infinites and NANs), called unnormalized numbers.

Consequently,

- The smallest value for the fractional part `(1+2^(-m)*significand)` is 1, the biggest value is `2-2^(-m)` (in your case 2-2^(-20), approximately 1,999999046).
- The smallest non-exceptional value for the total exponent `exponent-bias` is `-2^(e-1)+2` (in your case -14), the biggest is `2^(e-1)-1` (in your case: 15).

So it turns out that:

- The smallest (positive) normalized number that can be represented is `2^(-2^(e-1)+2)` (in your case 2^(-14), approximately 0,000061035)
- The biggest is `(2-2^(-m))*(2^(2^(e-1)-1))` (in your case (2-2^(-20))*(2^15), approximately 65535,96875).

As for "machine precision", I'm not sure what you mean, but one calls `m+1` (21 here) the binary precision, and the precision in terms of decimal digits is `log10(2^(m+1))`, for you this is approximately 6.3.

I hope I didn't get anything wrong, I'm no expert about this.